# How to implement Gaussian Mixture for VAE?

Tags: tensorflow, distribution, gaussian, tensorflow-probability, mixture

I feel like I don't really know what I'm doing so I will describe what I think I'm doing and what I want to do and where that fails.

Given a normal variational autoencoder:

```
...
net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=code_size * 2, activation=None)
mean = net[:, :code_size]
std = net[:, code_size:]
posterior = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiagWithSoftplusScale(mean, std)
net = posterior.sample()
net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=input_size, ...)
...
```

What I think I'm doing: Let the neural network find a "mean" and "std" value and use it to create a Normal distribution (Gaussian).
Sample from that distribution and use that for the decoder.
In other words: learn a Gaussian distribution of the encoding

Now I would like to do the same for a mixture of Gaussians.

```
...
net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=code_size * 2 * code_size, activation=None)

means, stds = tf.split(net, 2, axis=-1)

means = tf.split(means, code_size, axis=-1)
stds = tf.split(stds, code_size, axis=-1)

components = [tfd.MultivariateNormalDiagWithSoftplusScale(means[i], stds[i]) for i in range(code_size)]
probs = [1.0 / code_size] * code_size

gauss_mix = tfd.Mixture(cat=tfd.Categorical(probs=probs), components=components)
net = gauss_mix.sample()
net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=input_size, ...)
...
```

That seemed relatively straight forward for me except that it fails with the following error:

> Shapes () and (?,) are not compatible

This seems to come from `probs` that doesn't have the batch dimension (I didn't thought it would need that).

I thought that `probs` defines the probability between the components.

If I define a `probs` that also has the batch dimension I get the following cryptic error I don't know what it should mean:

> Dimension -1796453376 must be >= 0

**Do I generally misunderstand some concepts?**

**Or what do I need to do differently?**